# Is it possible to update an existing opportunity in Salesforce using apex SOQL query?

Tags: soql, query, update, record

I have a business requirement to update / close an existing opportunity in Salesforce automatically. I have an existing script that extracts record from salesforce automatically using soql query and I am wondering if it is also possible to use SOQL to insert/update data in Salesforce.

Comment: Don't confuse `SOQL` with `SQL`. I can appreicate that, given that in `SQL` you'd use something akin to `INSERT INTO Contact (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('Foo', 'Bar')`, Salesforce is very different.

Comment: Hi Christine - no, SOQL is only for retrieval of records. There are a lot of acronyms thrown around in Salesforce development and I know it can be confusing, so to answer your question - no, SOQL cannot insert/update data.

Comment: I have an existing script that extracts data from salesforce and I'm wondering how can I use this to update data in Salesforce. I am just new in Apex and needed all the help I can get. Thanks again:

Comment: Here's the extract script:  <bean id="csvExportOpportunityProducts"
        <property name="name" value="csvExportOpportunityProducts"/>
            <map>
                <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="OpportunityLineItem"/>
  <entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" value="Select OpportunityID, PricebookEntryID, Quantity, UnitPrice FROM OpportunityLineItem "/>
                <entry key="process.operation" value="extract"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

Answer (score 6):

No, SOQL (Salesforce Object Query Language) is a *query language*. It allows you to pull data *from* the database. If you want to push data *to* the database, you use DML (Database Manipulation Language) operations.

Basic Example:

```
List<Opportunity> records = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE ...];
// above is SOQL

// set some fields...

update records;
// above is DML
```

Comment: Didn't see this answer in the review queue before I commented. Good answer!

Comment: Thanks Adrian.Maybe you can help me transform my extract script to update record: <bean id="ExportOppProds"
        <property name="name" value="ExportOppProds"/>
            <map>
                <entry key="sfdc.endpoint" value=""/>
                <entry key="sfdc.username" value=""/>
                <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="OpportunityLineItem"/>
  <entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" value="Select OpportunityID,  Quantity, UnitPrice FROM OpportunityLineItem "/>
                <entry key="process.operation" value="extract"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

Comment: @ChristineP. That seems like an entirely separate question. Take a moment to visit the [faq] and the [help], and read [ask]. Perhaps you should ask a new question about your export script specifically.